# Allow Ktorrent to only run on one network

Tags: networking, kde, manjaro, bittorrent

I'm a student at university but live in privately rented accommodation. Is it possible to set Ktorrent so that it only runs when I'm using my 'home' network (if I run it at uni my wifi account gets suspended)?

PS I use Manjaro Linux